# Boost test case mixing dataset and template

Tags: c++, boost, boost-test

I'm using boost.test for unit testing (currently using boost 1.71.0). I have a template class I would like to test with a dataset.

I could only find ways to test on different template parameters (using `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE`) or on a dataset (using `BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE`). But i couldn't find a way to mix both template and dataset.

Here is a MWE of what I achieved to do, and commented what I'm trying to do.

`test.cpp`:

```cpp
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE data_template
#include <boost/mpl/list.hpp>
#include <boost/test/data/test_case.hpp>
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <numeric> // std::accumulate

template <typename C>
struct Testee{
    C container;
    typename C::value_type f(){
        // just a dummy function to be tested
        return std::accumulate(container.begin(),container.end(),0);
    }
};

typedef boost::mpl::list<std::vector<double>, std::list<double>, std::vector<size_t>> container_types;

template <class T> void test_containers(size_t size)
{
    Testee<T> t;
    t.container = T(size,1);

    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(t.f(), size);
}

// test on all container types but only with size=100 (3 test cases)
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(test1, T, container_types)
{
    test_containers<T>(100);
}

// test with several container sizes but only for vector<double> (6 test cases)
BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE(test2, boost::unit_test::data::make({0, 1, 2, 10, 100, 1000}), size)
{
    test_containers<std::vector<double>>(size);
}

// What I'm looking for looks like:
// // test for each combination of container type and size (6*3=18 test cases)
// BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE_TEMPLATE(test3, T, container_types, boost::unit_test::data::make({0, 1, 2, 10, 100, 1000}), size)
// {
//     test_containers<T>(size);
// }
```

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED( VERSION 3.5 )
PROJECT(data_template_test
    LANGUAGES CXX)

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++17 -Wall ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")

find_package(Boost 1.59 REQUIRED COMPONENTS unit_test_framework)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Boost::unit_test_framework)
target_compile_definitions(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK)
```

The MWE produces 9 test cases that pass without errors, but I want the combination of all types with all sizes, so 3x6=18 test cases.
Is there any way to do that using boost-test? Maybe using some more verbose / less friendly API?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution to testing this? Though I don't know how this would be implemented, as each template might require different data. I'm thinking about a fixture that is specialized with data.